# Unable to save to variable in Class?

Tags: c++

Beginner code. Compiles fine. SetMemo seems to work (as it repeats the input) but when I try to use ReadMemo, savedmemo seems to be NULL. Anything else included in the line will print, except that. What am I doing wrong? Am I accidentaly wiping the variable elsewhere?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int firstboot = 1;

class MEMOCLASS {
    public:
    void SetMemo(string memoinput_pvt) {
        savedmemo = memoinput_pvt;
        cout << savedmemo << " saved as a memo!" << endl;
        };
    string ReadMemo(){
        return savedmemo;
    };
    private:
    string savedmemo;
};

int main()
{
    MEMOCLASS MMObj;
    string input;
    string memoinputmain;
    if (firstboot == 1) {
        cout << "Hello! Please use \"write memo\" to store a memo or \"read memo\" to read a previously stored memo. Type \"exit\" to quit the programme." << endl;
        firstboot = 0;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Ok, anything else I can do for you?" << endl;
    }
    getline(cin, input);
    if (input == "write memo") {
        cout << "Ok, go ahead. Press Enter to record the Memo.\n";
        getline(cin, memoinputmain);
        MMObj.SetMemo(memoinputmain);
        main();
    }
    else if (input == "read memo") {
    cout << "The memo reads: " << MMObj.ReadMemo() << endl;
    main();
    }
    else if (input == "exit")
    {
        cout << "Cya!\n";
        return 0;

    }
    else if (input == "help")
    {
        cout << "Use \"write memo\" to store a memo or \"read memo\" to read a previously stored memo. Type \"exit\" to quit the programme.\n";
        main();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid input!\n";
        main();
    }
}
```

Comment: `main();` C++ does not allow you to call `main` - you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Each recursive call of a function has unique instance of every non-static local variables. You made `firstboot` a global variable, what about `MMObj`?

Comment: They idiomatic way to do something like this is not via recursion, but using a simple `while(true)` loop and `break;`ing when one is done. The `else if` already guarantees that only one of the blocks is executed, otherwise there would be `continue;` to skip parts of a loop iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two problems:

1. In C++ you're not allowed to call [the `main` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) recursively. Use loops instead. (Calling `main` in any way, no matter from where, in your code is formally [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).)
2. Because you call `main` recursively, each call results in a ***new*** and distinct variable `MMObj` being created.

Comment: shouldnt 2. be "Because you call `main`, anything could happen" ? Currently it sound as if it is something to rely on, but afaik calling `main` is undefined

Comment: @user463035818 Fair, but trivial though.

Comment: @user463035818 don't forget, undefined can also include works as expected... If the compiler has defined that that's what it will do, then while the code may not be portable to other compilers the result is well defined for that compiler.

Comment: @user463035818 Of course it's UB from a formal point of view, but as with just about all undefined behaviors the implementation can still do something. And in this case it's clearly handling it as a "normal" recursive function call.

Comment: @UKMonkey no when it is undefined then it is undefined and you cannot rely that if it works once then it will always work (even with the same compiler). What you describe is rather implementation defined. I just think one should be careful with UB. But nevermind, it was a minor nitpick

Comment: well, I just found out that in C you are allowed to call `main`. Considering that, I wouldnt expect a velociraptor jumping through my window if I do the same in C++. Now I wonder why there is this difference between C and C++.

Comment: It worked. Removed all calls to main, moved firstboot into main, added a while loop underneath "string memoinputmain;" and it magically worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user463035818 Probably due to the wording regarding the destroying of object with static storage duration. [basic.start.term]

Answer (score 1):

First, a point to bear in mind. You shouldn't call `main`.

Now, when you do call main, the object you create ceases to exist.
Any code like

```
void foo()
{
    int x = 6;
    if (x == 6)
    {
        x = 7;
    }
    foo();
}
```

will make a new `x` when it gets called again, giving `x` with the value 6.

You can pass in your objects to keep them around.

```
void foo(int x)
{
    if (x == 6)
    {
        x = 7;
    }
    foo(x);
}
```

In your case, make a new function, e.g. `runMMObj`

```
MEMOCLASS runMMObj(MEMOCLASS MMObj) //you know this is a copy, right?
{
    //do reads and writes here
    return MMObj;
}

int main()
{
    MEMOCLASS MMObj;
    MMObj = runMMObj(MMObj);
    //rerun your new function if you want
}
```